# Local WordPress Setup Won't Change Page Content on New Link

Tags: html, wordpress, localhost

I'm working on a local WordPress setup using MAMP and am unable to get my pages to display new content other than the index.php file.

I currently have two pages: index.php and information.php.

When I click the link in the navigation bar, it redirects me to the information.php page, but the content within that file is not displayed.

I've checked all the usual things (ie. browser cache, permalinks, .htaccess to allow override), but can't seem to make any headway.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Please let me know if you need to see any additional code as well.

header.php

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" href="main_hubs/information.php">Information
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

information.php and index.php

```
<?php get_header();?>
**Updated Content Here***
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress loads everything on the index.php of your installation and then it uses a routing system.

To be able to use information.php you must add it to your current theme and then add a snippet in the functions.php that makes the relation between a slug of a page to a .php file.

For instance: This code looks for a page that has the slug "information" and if found it will load the information.php file on the theme.

```
add_filter('page_template', 'my_custom_template');
 function my_custom_template($page_template) {
     if (is_page('information')) {
         $page_template = dirname(__FILE__).'/information.php';
     }
     return $page_template;
 }
```

This link is also very helpful in how wordpress works with links and slugs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Your filter and function name don't match; or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for that, If you create a page with that slug it will load your .php.
Don't forget to use the single.php as an example when making your page.

Comment: Much appreciated @SimonBerton! I completely forgot about the slug relation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your wp-admin panel > setting > permalinks choose your links according to your page url which is just below your title of your page. I think this would work if not pls let me know.